# Inserting a web image to an Excel cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm very much a newbie with Excel VBA so I would greatly appreciate any help.  I found the following code on the web to get an image into a spreadsheet.  The code as is can get the image and put that image on the activesheet but I need to have that image in a cell.  Is that possible?  Below is the macro that I currently have.

So column A will be the value that `getImage2` will use and Column B ideally should have the respective images.

```
Public Function getImage2(ByVal name As String) As String

  Dim imgURL As String

  Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

  XMLhttp.setTimeouts 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000

  imgURL = "http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/" + name + "/image"


  XMLhttp.Open "GET", imgURL, False

  XMLhttp.send

  If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then

   'It exists so get the image

    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture imgURL, msoFalse, msoTrue, 100, 100, 250, 250

  Else

    '
  End If

End Function
```

Comment: Does the URL ending with `/image` actually send to an image? It might be expecting something like `/image/img1.jpg`?

Comment: You cannot put an image "in" a cell - it can only be positioned "over" the cell(s)

Comment: @BruceWayne - see for example http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/aspirin/image

Comment: Quick random question - are you using this to study perhaps?  I just ask, because you could also do it where the image doesn't show up until you hover the mouse over the cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Public Function getImage2(ByVal name As String) As String

  Dim imgURL As String
  Dim x&, y&, wdth&, hght& ' using "&" is the same as "As Long"
  Dim cellFunctionRunsOn As Range
  Dim img

  Set cellFunctionRunsOn = Columns(1).Find(what:=name)

  Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

  XMLhttp.setTimeouts 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000

  imgURL = "http://cactus.nci.nih.gov/chemical/structure/" + name + "/image"


  XMLhttp.Open "GET", imgURL, False

  XMLhttp.send

  If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then

   'It exists so get the image
    x = Range(cellFunctionRunsOn.Offset(0, 1).Address).Left
    y = Range(cellFunctionRunsOn.Offset(0, 1).Address).Top
    wdth = Range(cellFunctionRunsOn.Offset(0, 1).Address).width
    hght = Range(cellFunctionRunsOn.Offset(0, 1).Address).height

    Set img = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=imgURL, linktofile:=msoFalse, savewithdocument:=msoTrue, Left:=x, Top:=y, _
        width:=wdth, height:=hght)
    img.Placement = xlMoveAndSize

  Else

  End If

End Function
```

This will get your image, then put it "in" the cell.

Note: As @TimWilliams mentions, you can't technically put it inside the cell.  What the above does is, it takes your Image and resizes it to the same height and width of the cell.  So, if you want a bigger image, then make the cell size bigger.

Comment: FYI - you only need to make a HEAD request to check if the content is available: GET will fetch the entire response, but HEAD will just get you the headers including "200 OK".  Saves making a double request per structure.

Comment: @TimWilliams - I'm pretty green when it comes to this kind of internet use with VB...so if I wanted to just use `HEAD`, would I just replace the `GET` with `HEAD` here:  `XMLhttp.Open "GET", imgURL, False` ?

Comment: @BruceWayne - yes - that's all you need to do.  E.g. http://www.jpsoftwaretech.com/vba/validate-url/